# Meaning of 文明を一層促進するための治世を開く

Tags: translation

> […] その天の命により、陛下がこのたび皇帝として即位し、天下を平和にし、文明を一層促進するための治世を開かれました。

My rough interpretation:

> By virtue of the Mandate of Heaven, Your Majesty now sits on the throne as an emperor, keeps all the world in peace and launched a policy to promote culture more than ever (?)

I'm really not sure about the last part, can someone help me? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

`文明` is "civilization".  I would say the last part would be "and reigns to bring peace to the world and to yet further civilization".